# Mask Textbox C# 2016 for Persian Date?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datetime, textbox

I use a Mask Text box in c# 2016 for Persian Date for accepting such date:

1367/1/1

I set Right to left to True and set mask to 00 /00 /0000 . all things is okey but user must input 1367/01/01. I want to capable this mask text box for times when user input 1367/1/1 then the text box replace 1367/01/01  (i.e add zeros for month and day). any comments should be highly appropriated.

Comment: winforms? wpf? asp.net?

Comment: @DanielA.White I add it, winforms

Comment: Off-topic but it should be left to right. In Persian language, numbers and dates are written left to right.

Comment: As a good open source Persian control library which provides Persian DatePicker and some other useful controls, I recommend using [FarsiLibrary](https://github.com/HEskandari/FarsiLibrary) which is created by [@HadiEskandari](http://stackoverflow.com/users/54538/hadi-eskandari).

Comment: See [MaskedTextBox.Mask Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask(v=vs.110).aspx) 0 is manditory, # is optional digit. So your mask would be 0000/#0/#0

Answer (score -1):

You might consider adding a KeyUp event method that looks like the following:

```
private void maskedTextBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        //check for slash press
        if (e.KeyValue == 191)
        {
            //split the input into string array
            string[] input = maskedTextBox1.Text.Split('/');

            //save current cursor position
            int currentpos = maskedTextBox1.SelectionStart;

            // currently entering first date part
            if (currentpos < 3)
            {
                // add leading 0 if number is less than 10
                if ((Int32.Parse(input[0]) < 10) && (!input[0].Contains("0")))
                {
                    input[0] = '0' + input[0];
                    currentpos++;
                }
            }
            // currently entering second date part
            else if ((currentpos < 6) && (currentpos > 3))
            {
                // add leading 0 if number is less than 10
                if ((Int32.Parse(input[1]) < 10) && (!input[1].Contains("0")))
                {
                    input[1] = '0' + input[1];
                    currentpos++;
                }
            }
            // currently entering last date part
            else
            {
                // do nothing here!
            }
            // set masked textbox value to joined array
            maskedTextBox1.Text = String.Join("/",input);
            // adjust the cursor position after setting new textbox value
            maskedTextBox1.SelectionStart = currentpos;
        }
    }
```

This would allow the person entering to enter 1/1/2016 and as they typed the '/' key it would update any values under 10 in the first two date parts and output = 01/01/2016.

Comment: @Peter4499 - Your comment above should have been in the form of an answer.  Also, if it was I would down mark it as it does not meet the criteria of the OP.

Comment: @Peter4499 - Also, if you merely make the leading digit optional- then the user is still required to advance past the optional position with either a space or an arrow key press.  The method I suggest above eliminates that need for the two additional keystrokes and provides the output requested.